# The filename, directory name, or volum label syntax is incorrecr

Tags: sql-server, cmd

I got this error when i write this command:
mofcomp"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsofr SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided little or no information, my answer is based purely on the fact you have a spelling error and missing space. I have to assume that you have Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

```dos
"%__AppDir__%wbem\mofcomp" "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

I have also added the path to mofcomp as an added precaution.